# Correct ABI payload packaging to call another Contract's address

Tags: addresses, abi, encoding

Let's suppose I have the two following contracts, `Dest` and `Proxy`:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Dest {
  function foo(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 decimals, uint256 totalSupply, address sender, uint256 value) public {
    /*
     * Logic code Here
     */
    }

  function bar(address a, address b, address c, address d, uint256 e, address f, address sender, uint256 value) public {
    /*
     * Logic code Here
     */
  }
}

contract Proxy {
  address private _owner;
  address private _dest;

  constructor(address dest) public {
    _owner = msg.sender;
    _dest = dest;
  }

  function getDest() public view returns(address) {
    return _dest;
  }

  function setDest(address dest) public {
    require(msg.sender == _owner);
    _dest = dest;
  }

  // Invoke takes msg.sender and msg.value and concatenates both to payload before to call the correct method
  function invoke(string memory method, bytes memory data) public payable {
    bytes memory payload = abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256(bytes(method)))), data, abi.encode(msg.sender), abi.encode(msg.value));
    (bool ok, bytes memory response) = _dest.call(payload);
  }
}
```

Both `foo` and `bar` methods in `Dest` contract have `address sender, uint256 value` as final input parameters.

The logic is that users will call `Proxy` passing the complete method signature and all abi encoded parameters **except for the last two**.

Proxy sequentially packs together method signature, partial call parameters, `msg.sender` and `msg.value` in a unique `bytes` packed payload, then invokes the `call` method on the `Dest` `address` using the packed payload as input.

The problem is that when the `foo` method is called, the value of `sender` input parameter is not the original `msg.sender` `address`, but contains some inconsistent value.

But everything works fine when the `bar` method is called.

My suspicion is that the problem is related to the fact that in the head of the input parameters of the `foo` method there are strings, which have variable length, while in `bar` there are only parameters with fixed length.

Any suggestion on how to build a general purpose solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot just concatenate partial ABI encodings, as ABI encoding splits variable length parameters into fixed and variable parts.  For function `Foo` the correct encoding would be:

```
selector (4 bytes)
name offset (32 bytes)
symbol offset (32 bytes)
decimals (32 bytes)
totalSupply (32 bytes)
address (32 bytes)
value (32 bytes)
name length (32 bytes)
name body (? bytes)
symbol length (32 bytes)
symbol body (? bytes)
```

When user encodes all `Foo` parameters except for the last two, the encoding probably looks like this:

```
selector (4 bytes)
name offset (32 bytes)
symbol offset (32 bytes)
decimals (32 bytes)
totalSupply (32 bytes)
name length (32 bytes)
name body (? bytes)
symbol length (32 bytes)
symbol body (? bytes)
```

When you append `msg.sender` and `msg.value`, you get:

```
selector (4 bytes)
name offset (32 bytes)
symbol offset (32 bytes)
decimals (32 bytes)
totalSupply (32 bytes)
address (32 bytes)
value (32 bytes)
name length (32 bytes)
name body (? bytes)
symbol length (32 bytes)
symbol body (? bytes)
msg.sender (32 bytes)
msg.value (32 bytes)
```

So the result is obviously incorrect.

Correct solution would be to first decode all the parameters into separate local variables using `abi.decode`, and then repack the back together with `msg.sender` and `msg.value` using `abi.encodeWithSignature`.  Something like this:

```solidity
string memory name;
string memory symbol;
uint256 decimals;
uint256 totalSupply;

(name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply) = abi.decode (
  data,
  (string, string, uint256, uint256));
bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature (
  method, name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply, msg.sender, msg.value);
```

Comment: Got it, extremely useful. Thanks. 
Because of I cannot know what payload contains (can be foo params, bar params or other method params if dest address changes in future), is it possible to call abi.decode without knowing parameters?

Comment: No, it is not possible as ABI encoding is not self-describing.  However what I could recommend is to make parameters that you want to substitute in `Proxy` to go before any other parameters, i.e. in the beginning of the encoding, and require the user to pass some (arbitrary) values for them, and `Proxy` will then overwrite these values in place.

Comment: In first release, sender and value were at start, but didn't worked, probably because of string offset mismatch. But now I understood your suggestion: pass address(0) and 0 as placeholders at start, then splice first 64bits and attach correct data. Hope to not have contract size problems (dest logic is really complicated). Will let you know, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need placeholders to preserve offsets.  Also, placeholders will allow users to use function signature as is without stripping replaceable parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thans to @Mikhail Vladimirov suggestions I solved the problem like this:

First of all, `sender` and `value` were placed as first and second input parameters in both `foo` and `bar` functions of the `Dest` contract.

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Dest {
  function foo(address sender, uint256 value, string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 decimals, uint256 totalSupply) public {
    /*
     * Logic code Here
     */
    }

  function bar(address sender, uint256 value, address a, address b, address c, address d, uint256 e, address f) public {
    /*
     * Logic code Here
     */
  }
}
```

Then the new logic in the `invoke` method of the `Proxy` contract replaces the first 64 bytes of the `bytes memory data` input parameters (32 for `address sender`, and 32 for `uint256 value`) with `msg.sender` and `msg.value`.

```solidity
contract Proxy {
  address private _owner;
  address private _dest;

  constructor(address dest) public {
    _owner = msg.sender;
    _dest = dest;
  }

  function getDest() public view returns(address) {
    return _dest;
  }

  function setDest(address dest) public {
    require(msg.sender == _owner);
    _dest = dest;
  }

  // Invoke takes msg.sender and msg.value and concatenates both to payload before to call the correct method
  function invoke(string memory method, bytes memory data) public payable {
    require(data.length >= 64, 'Insufficient space in payload');
    assembly {
        mstore(add(data, 0x20), caller())
        mstore(add(data, 0x40), callvalue())
    }
    bytes memory payload = abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256(bytes(method)))), data);
    (bool ok, bytes memory response) = _dest.call(payload);
  }
}
```

Of course, this means that, in the off-chain logic, the user **must** include a dummy `address` and dummy `uint256` as the first two parameters of `data` field when packaging input, to let the abi payload be coherent with offsets. Values are not important, because the SmartContract logic will discard them and replace with correct values.